# Css - vertical stack of containers with scrolls

Tags: html, css

I need vertical stack of blocks (may be with scrolls) contained in a fix-sized container (no scrolls). The number of visible blocks is managed dynamically from js code. Some blocks can be set hidden or visible. Visible blocks should occupy all free space after some block was hidden.

I used table element for this. But table cells are expanded vertically and whole table is expanded vertically beyond bottom size.

How I can fix table height? Or some other design may be used?

Here is HTML and CSS:

```css
table{
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}
div{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr><td><div>
        dsdgfsjafkgasfd sajhsadfhsafdsfsafs afsafsafsafsa fsafsafsafsafsaf
        asfsafsafsafsafsafs afsaffsfsasafsafsfa sfasfsafsafsaffsafsaffsafsa 
    </div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div>
        dsdgfsja fkgascfdsajhsadfhsafdsfsaf safsafsafsafs afsafsafsafsafsaf
        asfsafsafsaf safsafsafs affsfsasafsafsfa sfasfsafsafsaffsafsaffsafsa
    </div>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you forced to use a table for external container, or could you use anything else?

Comment: I can use anything else. The result display is above all.

Comment: If container has a fixed height and doesn't have a scrollbar, how can you show blocks exceeding its height?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with a fixed height container and a scrollbar. I've added borders to show both internal blocks and container: you can remove them if you want.

```
#container {
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

#content {
    border:1px solid green;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ydaLrpbe/1/)

Comment: I formulated problem more exact. Blocks should be in view, no scrolls.

Comment: Do you maybe mean that blocks should be displayed inline, not as blocks?

Comment: Think this blocks about as rectangular screen areas stacked vertically. If the design could be achieved with "inline" it'll be ok.

Comment: If you want both blocks stacked vertically and fixed height container, you cannot avoid a scrollbar for container (http://jsfiddle.net/ydaLrpbe/2/). Otherwise, container height is equal to the sum of blocks height (http://jsfiddle.net/ydaLrpbe/3/). If you want to have fixed height header (equal to the maximum block height) and inline blocks, you can use this (http://jsfiddle.net/ydaLrpbe/4/). Let me know what fits to your needs, and I will update the answer.

Comment: @BeloweeP. have you tried the proposed alternatives? What does fit better to your needs?

Comment: Apparently the problem has no solution in css terms. We should use javascript to dynamically calculate and set each block height.

Comment: @BeloweeP.: it depends, but first I need to understand what do you want.. what of the purposed alternatives is nearest to your idea? And from that solution, what should we change to get your goal? Please give some details, otherwise it's difficult to help.